# how to delay sip 183 in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

my calls did not receive ringback tones but went to the IVR system in less than 4 seconds. When reviewed the SIP captures on my end and noticed that the SIP 180 Ringing message is followed instantly by SIP 183 Session Progress with SDP. The SIP 183 with SDP is indicating that my asterisk server is ready to send through audio and since there is no ringing within  audio streams so, no ringback is observed. So, please tell me how to put delay in SIP 183.

I am using asterisk 1.4 in centos 5

Answer (score 1):

You can't put any delay in progress messages.

Actualy you can, but that require rewrite of chan_sip.c(posible, but costly)

You can remove 183 compleatly. See this article:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+progressinband